# taylor series expansion in laplace approximation of bayesian neural network prediction

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, pattern-recognition, taylor-series

In chapter 6 of the book Pattern recognition and machine learning, there is this part about prediction in Bayesian neural network using laplace approximation :[image: prml p.279 - bayesian neural network]

why assuming small variance compared with scales of w over which y(x,w) is varying leads to taylor series expansion of linear (5.169)(5.170)? I am just an undergraduate and novice in ml. can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the argument is the following:

1. We assume the posterior distribution of the weights vary relatively little. eg because priors are sufficiently restrictive or we have a lot of data.
2. A linear taylor series expansion will be effective in a small neighbourhood of a given point.  How small depends on how fast the gradient is changing around that neighborhood: ie based on the second derivative. (see Taylor series with remainder). eg if you are in an accelerating car, for a small enough time interval you can ignore the acceleration and assume you are going at constant speed (unchanging gradient) to estimate distance travelled